# How to clean filename using sed or regex?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I use an TCP Client in VB.NET to send an string to my ubuntu ncat server, which interpret that string and creates an file depending on the string.

***ClientToPHPSocket.sh***

```
while :
do
ncat -l 10000 -o "connectedclients.now"

unset n
while read -r code; do
  echo $code
  if [ ! -f "/var/www/html/servers/$code.txt" ]; then
    echo "0" > /var/www/html/servers/$code.txt
  fi
  slots=`cat /var/www/html/servers/$code.txt`
  slotsnow=`expr $slots + 1`
  echo $slotsnow > /var/www/html/servers/$code.txt
###CLEAN MISSION###
  ((n++))
  sed -i "$n d" connectedclients.now
done < connectedclients.now
done
```

My problem is that the filename get changed when using `echo $slotsnow > /var/www/html/servers/$code.txt`.

The result is `echo $slotsnow > /var/www/html/servers/$code^M.txt`.

I expect to clean the `^M` using sed or regex, but I am new with it. The result should be `echo $slotsnow > /var/www/html/servers/$code.txt`

Comment: The `^M` is a carriage return. Where do you get the contents of `$string` from? A file with Windows line endings? You should clean that (for example with `dos2unix`) instead of treating the symptom (carriage return in the string).

Comment: I updated my question and showed my socket shell script.

Comment: `connectedclients.now` has Windows line endings. Use `dos2unix connectedclients.now` before reading from it.

Comment: Perfect :) Post this as an answer if you like and I will accept it. Thanks alot!

Comment: I'm trying to find a good duplicate, because this has definitely been asked before. Just have to find the right one.